# Using TesseractOCR Objective-C framework with Swift iOS App (Bridging Header issues)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios and I am using the latest Xcode (version 7 beta 3) and am having issues with importing the bridging header. I have searched various sites and have found many people posting solutions such as removing a certain setting like the "Objective-C Bridging Header" from the tests target or only putting it in the project or target settings. I have tried to change "no" to "yes" in the Build Settings in "Always Search User Paths", but that to no avail. The framework I added to the project has a "headers" folder and within that is the TesseractOCR.h file. I have tried so many things, I feel that either my issue is some random setting I need to configure or something obvious that I do not know of, with me being a beginner in Swift and no knowledge of Objective C, I would appreciate any guidance.

In my bridging header file I have included

```
#import <TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h>
```

The two errors I get are

```
TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h file not found

Failed to import bridging header 'pathtoapp/AppName-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: Used same tutorial and got the same error.  Finally solved it by simply restarting Xcode.  Posting this so others reading it don't waste as much time as I did :-)

Answer (score 0):

In project navigator press CMD+N (New File) - iOS - Source - Objective-C File - "type any name you want" - Next button - Create button. Then you'll see alert asking you "Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?" - Yes.

**Done**, now just delete .m file because you don't need it. Thats all :)

Comment: I didn't get the alert asking me to configure the bridging header

Comment: Try restart settings in xcode. Paste this into terminal and try it again: defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

Comment: Nothing changed after I ran that in terminal

Answer (score 0):

add this to Library Search Paths

- $(inherited)
- $(PROJECT_DIR)/tesseract-ios-lib/lib

Answer (score -1):

Rename the "headers" directory to "Headers" on the TesseractOCR Framework

Comment: Why the down vote? I had exactly the same error and this solved it for me.